# Photo-resistor and leds

Tags: power-supply, photoresistor

I'm trying to build some system that would detect light and turn a 12v led strip ON.
The only power that I have available is a 9v battery.

I found some [Arduino compatible boards](https://www.lelong.com.my/xd-80-light-sensor-module-tonsin-150370431-2019-05-Sale-P.htm) but it seems overkill to use an Arduino for something that simple.

So I searched for a simple photo-resistor and found [this one](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B074QLFCF6/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_hTInFbVKB81XQ). However I am not sure it that will work.

My goal would be to wire the battery to the photo-resistor and the lamp in series and the photo-resistor would act as kind of a potentiometer effectively dimming the led strip as the light goes down.

However, I am not too sure about the values announced by the photo-resistor with a maximum of 150v dc (my 9v battery is way below so it should be no problem but is it actually enough then?) and a maximum of 100mW for which I am not sure if it shall be enough to power the le strip.

Small note:

- I do know that 9v is too low and thus the led strip is already not at its max brightness. I tested the leds and battery and it is working with sufficient brightness for my usecase.
- I have some size constraints and that is why I am looking for a solution that will be as small as possible

Comment: Do you want to turn the LED strip on or off if there is light? Did you consider that the LED light may affect the photoresistor if they are not optically separated?

Comment: The use case is very weird I know, but if should "follow" the light. So far I think the best way would be a voltage regulator and an ATTINY85 to read a photoresistor and using addressable leds so I can power it with the 9v but then control them with a pin of the ATTINY. Does it makes sense?

Comment: Yes that sounds good to me. You want to use a voltage divider with your photoresistor to read the voltage with the ATtiny. I think most adressable LEDs use 5V though, and if you have more than a handful, they require quite some current... I guess you know that your 9V battery will not last very long.
Other way to do it is to use a transistor driven by the photoresistor to switch a non-adressable LED strip.
In both cases it is important to mount the photoresistor away from the LEDs, else it will see its own light and stay on.

Comment: Yes the leds need to be up for about 20 to 30 minutes maximum. I found some led strip that will take 5v input and are addressable. The idea is to shut down the leds when the luminosity of the room is below a certain threshold so I guess it can be done this way. Also, you're right, the photoresistor will be mounted in a place where the leds cannot affect them. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, I will be using a L7805 as a voltage regulator to step down from 9 to 5v. I know I should be using capacitors in order to stabilize the output but in this case I don't think it is critical.

Comment: How much current will the LEDs draw when fully on? The L7805 might get too hot.

Comment: I just looked and I'll need about 30 to 50 cm of led band but not sure yet about density. So I found strips with 144 and 60 leds per meter which then goes from about respectively 14 to 6 watts. Doable??

Comment: Not with an L7805 and probably not with any linear regulator. Your lower value of 6 watts means 6W / 5V = 1.2A of current, and with a dropout voltage of 9V - 5V = 4V this equals a thermal loss of 4V * 1.2A = 4.8W in the L7805, you'd need a huge heatsink. For that amount of power you need a switching regulator.
But you will not get 1.2A out of a 9V battery anyway, if you're lucky you can get about 500mA for an hour, then it will be dead.
Bottom line: Use less powerful LEDs or you will need a stronger battery and a switching regulator.

Comment: Would it be better to find a 12v led strip powered with the 9v battery and using the L7805 only for the ATTINY85? Reason I am looking for individually addressable leds is so shutting down the LEDs is silent l. Though I'm not sure such strip would play nice with 9v. A simple led strip works but with lower luminosity.

Comment: Ok how about this: powering the ATTINY85 with a CR2032 and using a relay to shut down the leds which should be powered by the 9v battery as it is working today. No need for the L7805 at all then and it does not increase the amount of pins used. Does this sound better?